# Removing Specific Characters from Specific spots in a Python string

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a string that has a b' at the beginning and a ' at the end. It also has a \n after 21 characters, it seems that the API I am calling is adding these. How is the best way to remove these and only these.

Note: I can just remove up to the \n and readd the text that is supposed to be there since it never changes.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that the `b'` at the beginning and the `'` at the end are _part of_ the string?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Agree, they're probably the result of calling `repr`.

Comment: Yes I have tried printing out the string and they show. Like I said if there is a way where I could cut off the beginning a little and the end that would work.

Comment: If they're actually part of the string, you can get rid of them by passing the string to `ast.literal_eval()`, which will produce a bytestring (that's what the `b'...` does). You might want to double-check the API documentation instead of just stripping what it gave you.

Comment: From what you've said, we can't tell whether you have a `bytes` object and are misinterpreting the `b`, or whether you've somehow got a string which has the header of a bytes object's repr because of an erroneous conversion, or whether you really have a string which happens to have those characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `b'` and the `'` at then end are really part of the string, `s[2:-1]` would work. But problably they are just `repr` output which isn't actually part of the string.